Degeneracy of electrons in weak periodic potential
I have been trying to understand Aschroft's electrons in the weak periodic potential, but I do not understand some parts. Particularly following:
Why are we comparing the difference in kinetic energy of two different states (fixed k, different K) with the potential energy? Also, these are potential energy Fourier coefficients or what? How does this make sense in physical systems to make this assumption on the classification of degeneracy? In the picture below is the condition for non-degenerate states, for the degenerate states the sign is the opposite.
Thank you in advance!


You should at least state the problem in full. That is, copy out the entire setup of the question, so that people who do not have the book can have a chance of seeing where the problem comes from.
